# Как очистить таблицу от значений postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Как очистить таблицу House от всех значений. Сами столбцы оставить, нужно убрать содержимое. Сделал такой вариант, но мне нужно не в одном столбце, а по всем. Попробовать заменить "column" на "*"?

```
UPDATE "house" SET "column" = NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Команда](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/12/sql-delete) `DELETE` удаляет из указанной таблицы строки, удовлетворяющие условию `WHERE`. Если предложение `WHERE` отсутствует, она удаляет из таблицы все строки, в результате будет получена рабочая, но пустая таблица.

```
delete from house;
```

---

[Команда](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/12/sql-truncate) `TRUNCATE` быстро удаляет все строки из набора таблиц. Она действует так же, как безусловная команда `DELETE` для каждой таблицы, но гораздо быстрее, так как она фактически не сканирует таблицы. Более того, она немедленно высвобождает дисковое пространство, так что выполнять операцию `VACUUM` после неё не требуется. Наиболее полезна она для больших таблиц.

```
truncate house;
```